# Mapping a value in Helm 3 to another value

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm building a Helm 3 library chart and would like to convert an input value to another value that's based on a preset map.

Say my `values.yaml` includes the following value:

```yaml
global:
  environment: production # (production/staging/test/development)
```

I have the following convention for converting a long environment name to a short one:

```
production => prod
staging => stage
test => test
development => dev
```

I would like to use the value stored in `.Values.global.environment` to generate a deployment name that is prefixed with the **short** environment name. In this case, it should be mapped to
`prod-<application_name>`.

How can this be achieved with Helm 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a helper function under `templates/_helpers.tpl` file.

Unfortunately, there's no switch functionality in go templates so it has to be "dirty" if else

```
{{/*
Environment name mapping
*/}}
{{- define "my-chart.environment" -}}
{{- if .Values.global.environment -}}
{{- if eq .Values.global.environment "production" -}}
{{- printf "prod" -}}
{{- else if eq .Values.global.environment "staging" -}}
{{- printf "stage" -}}
{{- else if eq .Values.global.environment "test" -}}
{{- printf "test" -}}
{{- else if eq .Values.global.environment "development" -}}
{{- printf "dev" -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

then, use this template in the `my-chart.fullname` template

```
{{/*
Create a default fully qualified app name.
We truncate at 63 chars because some Kubernetes name fields are limited to this (by the DNS naming spec).
If release name contains chart name it will be used as a full name.
*/}}
{{- define "my-chart.fullname" -}}
{{- if .Values.fullnameOverride -}}
{{- .Values.fullnameOverride | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- else -}}
{{- $name := default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride -}}
{{- if contains $name .Release.Name -}}
{{- .Release.Name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- else -}}
##### ADDITIONAL LINES
{{- if .Values.global.environment -}}
{{- printf "%s-%s-%s" (include "my-chart.environment" .) .Release.Name $name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- else -}}
##### END ADDITIONAL LINES
{{- printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name $name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Test:

```
/apps/my-chart # helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.1.2", GitCommit:"d878d4d45863e42fd5cff6743294a11d28a9abce", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.8"}

/apps/my-chart # cat ./values.yaml
# Default values for my-chart.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare variables to be passed into your templates.

global:
  environment: development
```

Running `helm template .`
output:

```
...
...
# Source: my-chart/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dev-RELEASE-NAME-my-chart
...
...
```